# MS Access Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query expression NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am currently working in MS Access and are coming across this error when I got to execute my query. "Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query expression NOT EXISTS"

This is the query that is generating this error:

```
SELECT fName, lName, SSN
FROM Employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS
((SELECT storeID 
FROM Store
WHERE storeID = 3) 
EXCEPT
(SELECT orderID
FROM Works_On
WHERE  Employee.SSN = Works_On.SSN));
```

I have double checked spelling, syntax, and where I have my spaces and but I can't figure out what is causing this error, research online has also failed me  as well.

The results I want to achieve is having the name and SSN of all employees who work on an order who are from store 3.

Comment: I don't think MS Access supports `EXCEPT`.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: There is no `SELECT..EXCEPT` in Access.

Comment: Is there an alternative to except?

Comment: Your stated required result does not coincide with the SQL shown. Show sample data and desired output as text tables.